# Recover ext3 files from hard disk with bad sector

Tags: debian, ext3, fsck

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover formatted ext3 partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17243/recover-formatted-ext3-partition)

I have a folder of about 5GB that suddenly disappeared. When I checked its hard disk, I found out it has bad sector for about 2-3MB on this folder. Maybe it is on the folder's pointer.

The partition is EXT3 , and operating system is Debian.

I tried the fsck command , but it hasn't worked.

What should I do? How can I recover data? Any program or command?

Comment: first of all: Create an umage of that partition/drive and then work on that image.

Comment: @Arash Are the answers to the duplicate not the same as for your question? It doesn't really matter what the cause was, as long as the fix is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) will handle this.