# How to know what files got deleted?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04. yesterday from a Windows 7 partition, I accidentally deleted many files. I deleted by pressing `shift-del`.

Is there any way to know the name of the files that got deleted? If I'm able to get the names, I will make out how important the files are? If they are important I will try to recover or else I won't try. With no idea on whether log files can reveal that, I checked `syslog` file generated for that day but I couldn't find any information regarding that.

Comment: There will be no information in the Linux logs if you did this from Windows.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't generally any log that is maintained that keeps track of what files were deleted. About the only thing I can think of outside of trying to undelete the files using something like this Q&A: [undelete files from local fileserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/undelete-files-from-local-fileserver), is you could take a look at your system's `locate` command. It keeps a full list of all the files on a system, it's typically run nightly via cron, so you might find a list of the file names there, assuming you know what directories they were in.

#### Example

To get a list of all the files in my `$HOME` directory.

```
$ locate /home/saml | head -5
/home/saml
/home/saml/.Fontmatrix
/home/saml/.ICEauthority
/home/saml/.Trash
/home/saml/.VirtualBox
```

#### UPDATE #1

This approach would work so long as 2 conditions are met.

1. The Windows 7 partition was mounted during the window of time that the cronjob that runs the indexing of the HDD (typically this: `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`). This task runs daily, so if the partition is mounted one day but not the next, the data for that partition will get erased.
2. The `mlocate` crontab entry hasn't run yet, with those files now erased.

**NOTE:** This option is what I would consider a last ditch effort, something before resorting to actually attempting to recover the files using one of the many undelete methods covered on Unix & Linux. You have a very small window of opportunity to get a listing of files that were on your system from the `mlocate` database but have been deleted.

Comment: Great idea, +1! Perhaps the OP can compare the output of `locate` with the output of `locate --existing` and work from that.

Comment: @terdon - thanks, he'll have to work quickly though, I think the next time the locate cron runs the data will get lost.

Comment: Yup, but that depends on the settings in `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`, might even be earlier.

Comment: I ran `locate /boot | head -5`. If it had to output the files under `/boot` they why it gave outputs under `/etc`. For ex.: one line of output is `/etc/default/bootlogd`. In my case, as it was Windows partition which always needs to be mounted manually, I ran the command `locate /media/ravbholua/100EECEB0EECCB34
` but it returned no output.

Comment: @Ravi - it is pattern matching "/boot" in the string "/etc/default/bootlogd". If `locate` found nothing then this idea though valid is a dead end since the data for `/media` is likely gone now.

Comment: @Ravi - with this approach not helping you, I think you're only other option is to undelete the files using an appropriate method for NTFS. There isn't any other way that I'm aware of to get a listing of files.